# Using get method after use method(Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("In first middleware");
  next();
});

app.get((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("In second middleware");
  res.send("<h1>Hello From Express</h1>");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I'm just wondering how come the second middleware is not working when launching my application?

Comment: This says the first parameter to `get` is supposed to be a path. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass a path to app.get() as the first parameter. Copy pasting from [the docs.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is ok:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("In first middleware");
  next();
});
```

This is not:

```
app.get((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("In second middleware");
  res.send("<h1>Hello From Express</h1>");
});
```

As you're missing a *path* that will be calling this `GET` method.

So it could be

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
     res.send('my get request is working')
    })
```